# Neo4j 3.5 full-text search using only embedded API without Cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I use the new Neo4j 3.5 full-text search feature in my application. Currently I do it by executing Cypher through the embedded API.

```
public Result search(String term, String index) {
    // The query
    String cypherQuery = 
        "CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(\"" + index + "\", \"" + term + "\") YIELD node, score\n" + 
            "RETURN id(node), score";
    // Execute query
    return db.execute(cypherQuery);
}
```

I think this approach could be exploited to inject Cypher. Is there a way to execute a full-text search using only the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid Cypher injection attacks, you should pass the input as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/parameters/), as in:

```
public Result search(String term, String index) {
    // The query 
    String cypherQuery = 
        "CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes($index, $term) YIELD node, score\n" + 
        "RETURN id(node), score"; 
    // Execute query
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("term", term);
    params.put("index", index);
    return db.execute(cypherQuery, params);
}
```

[UPDATE]

NOTE: The use of parameters is officially recommended by neo4j. For example, to quote the Javadoc for the Java driver's [StatementRunner](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementRunner.html):

> Using parameters is highly encouraged, it helps avoid dangerous cypher
>   injection attacks and improves database performance as Neo4j can
>   re-use query plans more often.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely solves the injection vulnerability. Still, I wonder if there is a way to do this just with the API because that seems like an even cleaner solution and it might also have a performance advantage since the embedded API is generally faster.

Comment: See my update. This is the offically recommended approach.